# how can I connect solidity smart contract to an android application?

Tags: android, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, file-sharing

I currently work on the project which name "android document sharing using blockchain" I just want to know about how can I connect smart contract to connect my android android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WalletConnect mobile linking](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking) to communicate between Android apps and Ethereum wallets for signing the documents.

You can use [Web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) to communicate with Ethereum JSON-RPC.